# выделить подстроку, задающую вещественное число с фиксированной точкой

Tags: c++

задание: Из строки, состоящей из букв, цифр, запятых, точек, знаков + и – , выделить
подстроку, задающую вещественное число с фиксированной точкой.

Не знаю, правильно ли выполняю данное задание, подскажите пожалуйста.

Например: если ввести строку:  thy5.4v3f, выводит это: thy54v3f
thy5.4v3fММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММММthy5.4v3f, хотя должно выдать: 5.43

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <conio.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <cstring>


using namespace std;

int main() {
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    char str[81];
    char str_2[81];
    cout << "введите строку: ";
    cin.getline(str, 80, '\n');
    cout << str;
    int d;
    d = strlen(str);
    for (int i = 0; i <= d; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == '.' && isdigit(*str))
        {
                strcpy_s(str_2, str);
        }
    }
    cout << str_2 << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Вы тестировали свою программу? Она выводит то, что вы ожидали увидеть? Если да, то и проблем нет, а если же нет, то покажите, то что вводили, то что ожидали увидеть, и то что получили в итоге.

Comment: А что должно вывестись, если перед `.` будет не `5`, а какая-нибудь буква? А если точек несколько будет?

Comment: по идее, просто число. если точек несколько - то должна вывестись только первая точка. вроде бы так

Comment: мусор и должна быть в строке. Вы понимаете что  *str всегда имеет одно и то же значение?...

Comment: а как это тогда переделать?

Comment: Пройдясь дебаггером по своему коду, вы поймете, что `*str` указывает всегда на начало строки `str`, и первый символ этой строки, проверяется на то является ли он цифрой, если у вас в начале стоит буква, то условие всегда будет возвращать `false`.

Даже если, первый символ `str` будет цифрой, и в ней же будет `.`, то вы просто скопируете всю строчку `str` в `str_2`. Вам нужно в `str_2` выписать возможный `-` или `+`, потом все цифры, точку, и цифры до конца строки или до второй точки. Чтобы не было мусора в конце, нужно в конец `str_2` поставить `\0`, который означает конец строки

Comment: можете пожалуйста написать код по данному условию?

Answer (score 0):

Сразу  уточните, что размер строки не может быть изменен:
`const int  d = strlen(str)`;
Теперь нужны индексы начала и конца нужной подстроки:    `int first = 0, last = 0`;
Индекс всегда должен быть меньше размера строки, чтобы не читать завершающую ноль.  И  последний символ_точка, нас тоже не интересует, поэтому for (int i = 0; i < d - 1; i++) (а не i <= d).

Находим точку, проверяем является ли следующий символ цифрой. Если да, то это то что нам нужно. Проверяем по индексу `first`, является ли предыдущие символы цифрой? То же самое по индексу `last` проверяем последующие после точки символы. И используем подстроку [str[first],str[last]](я просто выведу на консоль).

```
for (int i = 0; i < d - 1; i++)    
    if (str[i] == '.' && isdigit(str[i + 1]))
    {
        first = i;
        last = i;
        if (i && last < d) {
            while (first && isdigit(str[first - 1]))
                --first;
        }
        while (++last < d && isdigit(str[last]));            
        while (first < last)
            cout << str[first++];  
        cout << '\n';
    }
```

Comment: почему-то не выводит числа, которые стоят до точки. только точку и числа, стоящие после неё

Comment: не знаю, я не проверял и не собираюсь. Я предоставил вам общую идею, а вам еще  и нужен готовый, отлаженный код?... Смотрите, отлаживайте, ведь вам самим что то нужно делать все таки.........